# How to add Unit Testing on my own, custom composer package?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, package, composer-php

I've made a little composer package.
My `composer.json` file as simple as it could be, it only contains name, description, author and something like that.

No `require` or `require-dev` object is provided.

I'm using PSR-4 autoloading system, and I have a directory structure like this:

```
|-author/package
|-- src/
|----MyClass.php
|-- tests/
|-- readme.md
```

And now I want to add unit testing for this package. 
I've created tests/ directory, but at this moment it's empty.

Can you tell me what should I do next to add unit testing for the package?

I've been searching for a while now on Google, and couldn't find any related answers.

P.S, it's a Laravel specific package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding PHPUnit in a decent version looks like the first step to do:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~4.5
```

This will place the `phpunit` executable in `vendor/bin/phpunit`. You can run it from there.

Comment: Thanks @Sven, after not getting answer here for a while, I thought that this is how it's done.

In my case, I also needed to "require" the package from illuminate to make it work.